# Run through loop for week and don't select weekends

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So the user can select 2 different dates, a start date and an end date from 2 calendars, when they click `add` the dates between&including the dates selected will be added to the Database, each date as a separate record.

This works fine however I don't want weekends to be added to the Database.

I've updated the UI of datepicker http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerCustomCellRender.html
but if a user selects fri-mon for example `fri,sat,sun and mon` will be added to the Database.
I've  tried to only run the code if datyofweek is not saturday or sunday

```
 public ActionResult listHolidays(Holiday holiday, int? PersonId, string HolidayDate, string endDate)
        {
            DateTime startDates = Convert.ToDateTime(HolidayDate),
                     endDates = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate);

            while (startDates <= endDates)
            {
                if (startDates.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday || startDates.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    Holiday holiday1 = new Holiday();
                    holiday1.PersonId = PersonId.Value;
                    holiday1.HolidayDate = startDates;

                    db.Holidays.AddObject(holiday1);
                    db.SaveChanges();


                     startDates = startDates.AddDays(1);
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

any help?
Thanks

Comment: If this is for a holiday system to calculate holidays, have you taken into account bank holidays as well as weekends - just a side note for you just incase!

Comment: no its not just to book holidays off...thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use AND instead of OR:

```
if (startDates.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && startDates.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

Your current condition will always be true. If `startDates` is `DayOfWeek.Saturday`, it is not `DayOfWeek.Sunday` and vice versa.

After that, you need to put the `startDates = startDates.AddDays(1);` outside the `if`.

Otherwise, you would have an endless loop, because as soon as `startDates` is `DayOfWeek.Saturday`, it will no longer be incremented.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if (startDates.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday || startDates.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

To

```
if (startDates.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && startDates.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

You'll then need to move this line

```
startDates = startDates.AddDays(1);
```

To outside of the `if` block (otherwise the `startDates` variable will never change if the date is a weekend date).

Answer (score 1):

If statement is wrong and day increment in wrong place.

```
            while (startDates <= endDates)
            {
                if (startDates.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday **&&** startDates.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    Holiday holiday1 = new Holiday();
                    holiday1.PersonId = PersonId.Value;
                    holiday1.HolidayDate = startDates;

                    db.Holidays.AddObject(holiday1);
                    db.SaveChanges();



                }

                **startDates = startDates.AddDays(1);**
            }
```

Comment: Please note: Formatting (such as bold) is not supported in code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative solution for you for calculating how many week days you have selected

```
List<DateTime> allDates = New List<DateTime>();
for (DateTime date = startingDate; date <= endingDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
    allDates.Add(date);
var days = allDates.Where(x => x.IsWeekday()).Count();
```

Using the following `DateTime` extension.

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
  public static bool IsWeekday(this DateTime dt)
  {
   return dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday;
  }
}
```

As per my comment, you can extend this to an `IsWorkday` if it is for a holiday system and encorporate some logic for checking if the day is a bank holiday.